# Copying one hidden div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, copy

I am facing a problem while copying One div to another.

The div I am copying has hidden parent div.

Problem is, after copying destination div did not show up even I also changed destination div style display to block but it did not show up. Their IDs are also different.

Source Div:

```
<div class="row" id="row31" style="display:none">
 <div class="column grid_8">
  <div id="row3bar1" class="chart" >
   <p> Hello World </p>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Destination div:

```
<div class="row3Model" id="row3modalChart">     
</div>
```

Coping Code:

```
var row11_updated_html = $('#row3bar1').html();
$('#row3modalChart').html(row11_updated_html);
```

Comment: shouldn't you use jQuery's clone() method instead?

Comment: It works perfectly for me using the code you gave. http://jsfiddle.net/dyhe2/

Comment: Yes its working in jsfiddle but not in my server. I have given <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> path

Comment: `display` property doesn't `inherit` by default. So you don't need to change any CSS. [**Read This**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly for me

```
$('#row3modalChart').html(row11_updated_html);
```